# contact form not connecting to email

Tags: wordpress, email

I am not techy, but I have built my own website using WordPress, via BlueHost as the hosting platform. I followed the Astra theme for my website. Everything works fine and the website is ready to go live apart from the contact form. When I test it, the message does not come through to my linked email address (Outlook email address). I am using WP forms for the contact form and I have downloaded the WP Mail SMTP plug-in as advised in an article I read. The notification emails are all set correctly to the email where I want to received etc. The exact error message I am receiving is "SMTP connect() failed", I have also had messages about authentication when trying to resolve this. I contacted Blue Host chat support, but they were not very helpful. Can anyone help?

Comment: @DipakDholakiya He already did that according to the question text. "*I have downloaded the WP Mail SMTP plug-in*"

Comment: Yes, but I think SMTP is not connected @Stender

Comment: Yeah - Could be a lot of things - permission issues, closed ports/protocols, misconfiguration, a setting in outlook. Who knows.

Comment: I am not techy enough to understand what to do next. Surely BlueHost should be able to support me with this?